# Revoke refresh tokens when signing out from IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

This my custom logout endpoint:

```
[HttpPost("logout")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LogoutAsync()
{
    await _interaction.RevokeTokensForCurrentSessionAsync();
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

It removes IdentityServer cookies but if a user at this time has a refresh_token he still can use it after logout. How to revoke all related refresh tokens? I tried using `IIdentityServerInteractionService.RevokeTokensForCurrentSessionAsync` but it doesn't work like expected.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with IdentityServer4, but I believe that if you really want to revoke refresh tokens, you have to add them on creating in database and delete them on logout. When user tries to get a new pair of access and refresh tokens, you'll check whether his refresh token in database. If not, it means that refresh token was revoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your client a SPA? If yes, delete the refresh_token from localstorage on logout action.

Also, you can make a POST request to this endpoint inside your custom logout function using HttpClient:

```
https://[Your_IdentityServer4_url]/connect/revocation
    token_type_hint=refresh_token
    client_id=[your_client_id]
    client_secret=[your_client_secret]
    token=[your_refresh_token]
```

Alternatively, you can use events to revoke refreshtoken on signout like this.

```
.AddCookie("cookie", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "mvccode";

        options.Events.OnSigningOut = async e =>
        {
            // revoke refresh token on sign-out
            await e.HttpContext.RevokeUserRefreshTokenAsync();
        };
    })
```

Link to the documentation - [here](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/web.html).

Comment: Deleting refresh_token from localstorage won't help if it was leaked

Comment: But refresh_token is useless without basic authentication (client_id and client_secret in this case). You will not have these stored any where. Right?

Comment: One more workaround is to manually go to "persistedgrants" table, search the row with the Key or Subject and change the expiration time to a time of past. That will cause the token to expired and cannot be re-used. What say?

Comment: client_id and client_secret are public for spa

Comment: Ok. I have modified my answer.